# JavaScript: Build email address from two strings (first name and last name)

Tags: javascript, forms, email, adobe

I am attempting a JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat to populate the email address (field: Email) based on the first name (field: FirstName) and last name (field: LastName) entered. Every email address will have the same domain (@company.com).

I found many resources on doing the opposite (to determine first and last name from email address) but  haven't found how to do this. I'm sure it's simple but I have not been using JavaScript very long.

This is getting me close:

```
//Populate requestor's email address based on requestor's name

//Email Address Object

var address = {
    "firstName":"FirstName",
    "lastName": "LastName"
}


//Email Address Function
function SetFieldValues (firstName, lastName) {
    this.getField("Email").value=address.firstName+"."+address.lastName+"@company.com"
}
```

My email address output is then

```
FirstName.LastName@company.com
```

I know that I have defined firstName and lastName as strings and that's the reason they are coming up in the output, but I am not sure how to have address change firstName and lastName based on what is entered into the fields on the form.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, are you really just asking how to change the adress object when someone types into an input element? If so, where's the input elements that you want to use to generate a new adress object ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
First Name: <input id="first_name_input">, Last name: <input id="last_name_input">
```

JavaScript:

```
var firstName = document.getElementById('first_name_input').value,
    lastName = document.getElementById('last_name_input').value;
```